# What packages are really required for Android Applications Development

Tags: android

I've a 40kb/s Internet. The Android SDK took me 1 and half hour to download(at first I thought it is packaged with all required packages). I am using Ubuntu 14.10(yea, it took me 11 hours to download).

I downloaded and installed Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Build-tools. In Android 5.0.1(API 21), I unticked both `Android TV whatever System Image` and both `Android Wear whatever System Image` because I am sure that I'm not going to use it.

My questions is what things are really required for Android applications development? Can anyone explain what are those packages for?

EDIT: I am not new to Java development. I have Java JDK 7, Eclipse(without the ADT plugin) and IntelliJ installed. I'm going to use IntelliJ as it is came with "Android Support" plugin)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: (Thanks!)I will not put those words next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading this packages will be enough for you

**SDK Platform** in Android 5.0.1 (API 21)

**Android SDK Tools 24.0.2** in Tools

**Android SDK Platform Tools 21**  in Tools

**Android SDK Build-tools 21.1.2** in Tools

Comment: Oh those only? Can you explain what are other packages for?

Comment: What kind of explain would you like to hear? Those packages would be enough for development. If you want to use Eclipse, also you have to download adt bundle following this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: The system image packages. What are those for?

Comment: System Image
Recommended. Although you might have one or more Android-powered devices on which to test your app, it's unlikely you have a device for every version of Android your app supports. It's a good practice to download system images for all versions of Android your app supports and test your app running on them with the Android emulator. For more information visit here http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Comment: I already saw that. You are copying from there. Also, "for more information visit here". I don't see "information" apart from that ._. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: I meant to say that you can get more information not only System Image but also other packages. Yes I copied explanation of System Image from that website. Thanks for accepted answer :) Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You need `eclipse`,`adt bundle` and `android sdk tool` that's it. No other thing is required for it.

Comment: Actually, you don't need eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need:

1. Eclipse IDE integrated with Android

   - Select Android version on which you're going to develop your application (Lolipop/KitKat etc) through SDk Manager
2. Java SDK (with JRE)